# Error compilar con pyinstaller (failed to execute script)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

realice mi primera aplicación GUI en Python, uso:
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Es un código de quizás 2000 líneas, bastante sencillo utilizando tkinter y sqlite3 para la base de datos,
he tratado de compilarlo y no lo he logrado, me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve leyendo tratando de encontrar que impide que se ejecute el programa y encontré un archivo que al parecer hacer referencia a los errores warn-index5.txt, pero al abrirlo, me aparece un listado que la verdad no se si son los errores que tiene mi script o si allí puedo ubicar la razón de porque no se ejecuta el programa, agradecería cualquier orientación que me puedan dar, llevo mas de un mes intentándolo y no he podido dar con el problema ó la solución.

Esto es lo que aparece el el archivo warn-index5.txt

```
This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
necessarily mean this module is required for running you program. Python and
Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional modules. 
For
example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.
```

Types if import:

- top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
- conditional: imported within an if-statement
- delayed: imported from within a function
- optional: imported within a try-except-statement

IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
yourself tracking down the missing module. Thanks!

```
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (optional), multiprocessing.util (delayed)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), xml.sax   
(delayed, conditional), setuptools.sandbox (conditional)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by 
importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc 
(optional), zipimport (top-level)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib 
(optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level), 
PyInstaller.loader.pyimod02_archive (delayed, conditional)
missing module named urllib.pathname2url - imported by urllib  
(conditional), PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph._compat (conditional)
missing module named _posixshmem - imported by 
multiprocessing.resource_tracker (conditional), 
multiprocessing.shared_memory (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by 
multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by 
multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional), 
future.backports.urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass 
(optional)
missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level), 
test.support (optional)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, 
optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, conditional, 
optional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional),  
numpy.distutils.cpuinfo (delayed, conditional, optional), 
babel.localtime._win32 (optional), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, 
conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by 
multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), 
multiprocessing.managers (top-level), multiprocessing.sharedctypes (top- 
level)
missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by 
multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by 
multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by 
multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy - imported by asyncio 
(delayed, conditional), asyncio.events (delayed, conditional)
missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, 
optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional)
missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional)
missing module named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile 
(optional), pathlib (delayed), distutils.archive_util (optional)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), 
shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed, conditional, 
optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), netrc 
(delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed), distutils.util (delayed, 
conditional, optional), distutils.archive_util (optional)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional), 
shutil (conditional)
missing module named 'win32com.gen_py' - imported by win32com 
(conditional, optional), C:\Users\Juan Carlos 
Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py (top-level)
missing module named pyimod03_importers - imported by 
PyInstaller.loader.pyimod02_archive (delayed, conditional), C:\Users\Juan 
Carlos Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py (top-level)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing' - imported by 
pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.markers (top-level), 
pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level)
missing module named _uuid - imported by uuid (optional)
missing module named __builtin__ - imported by numpy.core.numerictypes 
(conditional), numpy.core.numeric (conditional), numpy.lib.function_base 
(conditional), numpy.lib._iotools (conditional), numpy.ma.core 
(conditional), 
 numpy.distutils.misc_util (delayed, conditional), numpy (conditional), 
reportlab.lib.rl_safe_eval (delayed, conditional), reportlab.lib.utils 
(delayed, conditional), future.utils (conditional), future.builtins.misc 
(conditional), future.builtins.new_min_max (conditional), 
pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (conditional), 
setuptools._vendor.pyparsing (conditional)
missing module named ordereddict - imported by 
pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (optional), setuptools._vendor.pyparsing 
(optional)
missing module named StringIO - imported by 
PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph._compat (conditional), 
PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph.zipio (conditional), setuptools._vendor.six 
(conditional), numpy.testing._private.utils (conditional), numpy.lib.utils 
(delayed, conditional), numpy.lib.format (delayed, conditional), 
reportlab.lib.utils (conditional), babel._compat (conditional), 
pkg_resources._vendor.six (conditional)
missing module named 'com.sun' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs 
(delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named com - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs 
(delayed)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.packaging - imported by 
pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.appdirs - imported by 
pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.six.moves' - imported by 
pkg_resources (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements 
(top-level)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.six - imported by 
pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level), 
pkg_resources.py31compat (top-level)
missing module named 'multiprocessing.forking' - imported by C:\Users\Juan 
Carlos Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site- 
packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py (optional)
missing module named ttk - imported by tkcalendar.dateentry (optional), 
tkcalendar.calendar_ (optional), tkcalendar.tooltip (optional), 
future.moves.tkinter.ttk (conditional, optional)
missing module named future_builtins - imported by numpy.lib.npyio 
(conditional), reportlab (conditional), future.builtins.misc (conditional)
missing module named _dummy_threading - imported by dummy_threading 
(optional)
missing module named _dbm - imported by dbm.ndbm (top-level)
missing module named gdbm - imported by anydbm (top-level),  
future.moves.dbm.gnu (conditional)
missing module named _gdbm - imported by dbm.gnu (top-level)
missing module named dumbdbm - imported by anydbm (top-level),  
future.moves.dbm.dumb (conditional)
missing module named anydbm - imported by future.moves.dbm (conditional)
missing module named dbhash - imported by anydbm (top-level)
missing module named whichdb - imported by future.moves.dbm (conditional), 
anydbm (top-level)
missing module named dummy_thread - imported by numpy.core.arrayprint 
(conditional, optional), future.backports.misc (conditional, optional)
missing module named thread - imported by numpy.core.arrayprint 
(conditional, optional), PyInstaller.loader.pyimod02_archive 
(conditional), 
future.backports.misc (conditional, optional)
missing module named Tkinter - imported by tkcalendar.dateentry 
(optional), tkcalendar.tooltip (optional), future.moves.tkinter 
(conditional, optional)
missing module named cdecimal - imported by babel._compat (conditional, 
optional)
missing module named cPickle - imported by reportlab.lib.utils (optional), 
babel._compat (conditional)
missing module named copy_reg - imported by numpy.core (conditional), 
cPickle (top-level), cStringIO (top-level)
missing module named cStringIO - imported by cPickle (top-level), 
babel._compat (conditional)
missing module named sets - imported by reportlab.platypus.doctemplate 
(optional), pytz.tzinfo (optional)
missing module named UserDict - imported by pytz.lazy (optional)
missing module named tkFont - imported by tkcalendar.calendar_ (optional)
missing module named PyQt5 - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, 
optional)
missing module named AppKit - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, 
optional)
missing module named Foundation - imported by pyperclip (delayed, 
conditional, optional)
missing module named PyQt4 - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, 
optional)
missing module named 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' - imported by pyperclip (delayed, 
optional)
missing module named qtpy - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, 
optional)
missing module named gtk - imported by pyperclip (delayed, conditional, 
optional)
missing module named tests - imported by reportlab.platypus.tables 
(conditional)
missing module named htmlentitydefs - imported by 
reportlab.platypus.paraparser (conditional)
missing module named HTMLParser - imported by 
reportlab.platypus.paraparser (conditional)
missing module named pyphen - imported by reportlab.platypus.paragraph 
(optional)
missing module named reportlab.platypus.cleanBlockQuotedText - imported by 
reportlab.platypus (conditional), reportlab.platypus.paraparser 
(conditional)
missing module named rlextra - imported by reportlab.lib.pdfencrypt 
(delayed, optional)
missing module named pyaes - imported by reportlab.lib.pdfencrypt 
(optional)
missing module named jarray - imported by reportlab.lib.utils (delayed, 
conditional, optional)
missing module named 'javax.imageio' - imported by reportlab.lib.utils 
(delayed, conditional)
missing module named rl_config - imported by reportlab.lib.utils (delayed, 
conditional, optional)
missing module named urllib2 - imported by numpy.lib._datasource (delayed, 
conditional), reportlab.lib.utils (conditional)
missing module named 'reportlab.lib.pyHnj' - imported by 
reportlab.lib.utils (delayed, optional)
missing module named Image - imported by reportlab.lib.utils (conditional, 
optional)
missing module named 'java.awt' - imported by reportlab.lib.utils 
(delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named javax - imported by reportlab.lib.utils (conditional, 
optional)
missing module named macostools - imported by reportlab.lib.utils 
(conditional)
missing module named macfs - imported by reportlab.lib.utils (conditional)
missing module named md5 - imported by reportlab.lib.utils (optional)
missing module named pyfribidi2 - imported by reportlab.pdfgen.textobject 
(conditional, optional)
missing module named reportlab_mods - imported by reportlab (optional)
missing module named 'reportlab.local_rl_mods' - imported by reportlab 
(optional)
missing module named cffi - imported by PIL.Image (optional), PIL.PyAccess 
(top-level), win32ctypes.core (optional), PIL.ImageTk (delayed, conditional, 
optional)
missing module named olefile - imported by PIL.MicImagePlugin (top-level), 
PIL.FpxImagePlugin (top-level)
missing module named 'PySide2.QtCore' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, 
optional)
missing module named PySide2 - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, 
optional)
missing module named 'PyQt5.QtCore' - imported by PIL.ImageQt (conditional, 
optional)
missing module named commands - imported by numpy.distutils.cpuinfo 
(conditional)
missing module named setuptools.extern.packaging - imported by 
setuptools.extern (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), 
setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.six' - imported by setuptools (top- 
level), setuptools.extension (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.version' - imported by 
setuptools.config (top-level), setuptools.msvc (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.six.moves.filterfalse - imported by 
setuptools.extern.six.moves (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), 
setuptools.msvc (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.six.moves.filter - imported by  
setuptools.extern.six.moves (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), 
setuptools.ssl_support (top-level), setuptools.command.py36compat (top-level)
missing module named _manylinux - imported by setuptools.pep425tags (delayed, 
optional)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.utils' - imported by 
setuptools.wheel (top-level)
missing module named wincertstore - imported by setuptools.ssl_support  
(delayed, optional)
missing module named 'backports.ssl_match_hostname' - imported by 
setuptools.ssl_support (optional)
missing module named backports - imported by setuptools.ssl_support 
(optional)
missing module named 'setuptools._vendor.six.moves' - imported by 
'setuptools._vendor.six.moves' (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.pyparsing' - imported by 
setuptools._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level), 
setuptools._vendor.packaging.markers (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.six.moves.map - imported by 
setuptools.extern.six.moves (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), 
setuptools.command.easy_install (top-level), setuptools.sandbox (top-level), 
setuptools.package_index (top-level), setuptools.ssl_support (top-level), 
setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level), setuptools.namespaces (top-level)
runtime module named setuptools.extern.six.moves - imported by 
setuptools.dist 
(top-level), setuptools.py33compat (top-level), configparser (top-level), 
setuptools.command.easy_install (top-level), setuptools.sandbox (top-level), 
setuptools.command.setopt (top-level), setuptools.package_index (top-level), 
setuptools.ssl_support (top-level), setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level), 
setuptools.command.py36compat (top-level), setuptools.namespaces (top-level), 
setuptools.msvc (top-level), 'setuptools._vendor.six.moves' (top-level) 
missing module named setuptools.extern.six - imported by setuptools.extern 
(top-level), setuptools.monkey (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), 
setuptools.extern.six.moves (top-level), setuptools.py33compat (top-level), 
setuptools.config (top-level), setuptools.command.easy_install (top-level), 
setuptools.sandbox (top-level), setuptools.py27compat (top-level), 
setuptools.package_index (top-level), setuptools.wheel (top-level), 
setuptools.pep425tags (top-level), setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level), 
setuptools.command.sdist (top-level), setuptools.command.bdist_egg (top- 
level), setuptools.unicode_utils (top-level), setuptools.command.develop 
(top- 
level)
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.cpuinfo' - imported by 
numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.fcompiler' - imported by 
numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.command' - imported by 
numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named numpy_distutils - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose 
(delayed, optional)
missing module named __svn_version__ - imported by numpy.f2py.__version__ 
(optional)
missing module named numarray - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info 
(delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named Numeric - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info 
(delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named ConfigParser - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info 
(conditional), numpy.distutils.npy_pkg_config (conditional)
missing module named _curses - imported by curses (top-level), curses.has_key 
(top-level)
missing module named pytest - imported by numpy._pytesttester (delayed), 
numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named 'nose.plugins' - imported by 
numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level), 
numpy.testing._private.nosetester (delayed)
missing module named scipy - imported by numpy.testing._private.nosetester 
(delayed, conditional)
missing module named 'nose.util' - imported by 
numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level)
missing module named nose - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils (de 
layed, 
optional), numpy.testing._private.decorators (delayed), 
numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level)
missing module named psutil - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils 
(delayed, optional)
missing module named numpy.core.number - imported by numpy.core (delayed), 
numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.object_ - imported by numpy.core (top-level), 
numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.signbit - imported by numpy.core (delayed), 
numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.float32 - imported by numpy.core (top-level), 
numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.intp - imported by numpy.core (top-level), 
numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.lib.i0 - imported by numpy.lib (top-level), 
numpy.dual (top-level)
missing module named cpickle - imported by numpy.compat.py3k (conditional)
missing module named pickle5 - imported by numpy.compat.py3k (conditional, 
optional)
missing module named numpy.core.integer - imported by numpy.core (top-level), 
numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sqrt - imported by numpy.core (top-level), 
numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.conjugate - imported by numpy.core (top- 
level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sign - imported by numpy.core (top-level), 
numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)  

missing module named numpy.core.divide - imported by numpy.core (top-level), 
numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.geterrobj - imported by numpy.core (top- 
level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.add - imported by numpy.core (top-level), 
numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.complexfloating - imported by numpy.core 
(top- 
level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.inexact - imported by numpy.core (top-level), 
numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.cdouble - imported by numpy.core (top-level), 
numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.csingle - imported by numpy.core (top-level), 
numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.double - imported by numpy.core (top-level), 
numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.single - imported by numpy.core (top-level), 
numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named urlparse - imported by numpy.lib._datasource (delayed, 
conditional)
missing module named numpy.recarray - imported by numpy (top-level), 
numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.dtype - imported by numpy (top-level), 
numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.expand_dims - imported by numpy (top-level), 
numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.array - imported by numpy (top-level), 
numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords 
(top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.bool_ - imported by numpy (top-level), 
numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.iscomplexobj - imported by numpy (top-level), 
numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amin - imported by numpy (top-level), 
numpy.ma.core 
(top-level)
missing module named numpy.amax - imported by numpy (top-level),  
numpy.ma.core 
(top-level)
missing module named numpy.ndarray - imported by numpy (top-level),    
numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords 
(top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)   
missing module named numpy.histogramdd - imported by numpy (delayed), 
numpy.lib.twodim_base (delayed)
missing module named numpy.eye - imported by numpy (delayed), 
numpy.core.numeric (delayed)
```

Comment: Que comando usaste con pyinstaller?

Comment: pyinstaller --windowed --onefile index5.py, uso esta instrucción, me genere el exe lo ubica en dist, pero cuando ejecuta, aparece el error antes descripto.

Comment: Lee los [requerimientos](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/requirements.html#windows), y si cumples con todos intenta la sentencia `pyinstaller -w -F index5.py`.

Comment: Gracias  gcoronel99, seguí las instrucciones encontradas en requerimientos, aun así, me sigue generando el mismo error una vez que crea el exe

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, sugerencia para quienes están comenzando con python, al generar el exe deben llevar la database a fin de que la pueda leer, también las imágenes de uso del script, no lo vi al principio porque ejecutaba el script desde el explorador de windows y no alcanzaba a ver los errores, cuando lo ejecute desde la ventana de comando ubique rápidamente los errores, eran una tontearía.